# How do I prevent an arbitrary object's destructor from ever running in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting, destructor, reference-counting

### Context

I have a troublesome object from third-party code in a Python (3.10) program. The object is *not* written in pure Python; it's provided by an extension module.

Due to a bug in the third party code, when the object's destructor runs, the program blocks indefinitely (waiting for a mutex it will never get).

Attempts to fix the bug causing the indefinite blocking have failed, though I'm still trying.

### Question

How can I intentionally *prevent* a destructor from being called, ever, when Python shuts down?

For example, let's say I have the following code in `test.py`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __del__(self):
        print("bye")

x = MyClass()
```

What can I do to make sure that `x`'s destructor never runs, and "bye" is never printed--either when the program shuts down or when `x` goes out of scope?

### What I've tried

- I've tried forcing the program to exit via `os._exit` in a destructor that's guaranteed to run before the troublesome object's destructor. However, that causes other destructors that I do want to run to not do so. While I know destructor execution can't be guaranteed, this approach is throwing out rather a lot of good with the bad.
- I've tried intentionally creating a reference cycle involving this object, but the cyclic GC is too good for me to defeat simply.
- I've tried code like this, but it did not work:

```py
import ctypes
incref = ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef
incref.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
incref.restype = None
incref(x)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you contact whoever maintaining it or fork the code and fix it yourself instead of monkeypatching?

Comment: I have done both of those, and am working with the maintainers and on my own to attempt a fix. However, many weeks of working on these issues have not yielded working results, so I'm asking this question as a backup plan.